# Australia: eVisitor or ETA

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, australia

I intend to

- Fly from Cambodia to Sydney
- In Sydney board a cruise ship with Bahamas flag
- By said ship visit more places in Australia (Melbourne, Perth, ...)
- Leave by said ship towards Indonesia

Would that count as a single visit (=free eVisitor visa) where I just happen to use an alien transport vessel, or as multiple visits (=20AUD ETA visa) because I am legally in the Bahamas in-between?
From my experience, passports get only entry-stamped upon arrival at the first port and exit-stamp when leaving the last, but I just wanted to be sure ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know where you got the "single visit" thing from? An eVisitor can be used for as many visits as you like during its validity, only you cannot stay longer than 3 months each time.

As stated [here](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651-) (click on "What the eVisitor lets you do"):

> enter Australia for up to three months **during each visit** during the 12 months from the date the eVisitor is granted

So your question is void: there's no reason for a German to pay for an ETA rather than getting an eVisitor.

But in any case: when you clear immigration in Australia, you've entered/left the country, period.

Comment: Hm, the big blue box at the top of http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/651- sumarises "This visa lets you visit Australia: -  to visit or for business visitor purposes -  for up to three months at a time within a 12-month period.​" whereas  http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/601-#sub-heading-0 says "This visa lets you visit Australia: - to visit or for business visitor purposes - as many times as you want, for up to a year - and stay up to three months for each visit.​" So the eye-striking difference is that the latter has an additional bullet point that emphasizes multiple entry ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You're misunderstanding "three months at a time". It means 3 months during each visit, not 3 months in total within the 12-month period

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Click on "What the eVistor lets you do", and it'll say "enter Australia for up to three months **during each visit** during the 12 months from the date the eVisitor is granted"

Comment: Yes, I've stumbled across that "each" by now as well, which *implicitly* suggests that multiple entry is possible. I wonder why they then did not choose makesimilar formulations in both descriptions, though. Variation for stylistic reasons may not always be a good idea in legal texts ... :)